# Making "My billing address is same as above" checkbox work on webforms

Tags: webform-civicrm, billingblock

Currently, "My billing address is same as above" checkbox is not visible on webform-civicrm. I can see that billing fields are not part of a webform and they are loaded directly from civicrm using civicrm's billingBlock.js.

Please can I ask, if it is possible at all to make the checkbox work for webforms since the address fields are on a different page than the payments page? If yes, what would be the best way to do it?

Thanks!